# How to properly print Standard form of equation in Python

Tags: python, math, equation

When writing Ax + By + C = 0, my program keeps 1's next to x and y, not removing Ax By or C when there is a 0. I was hoping there was another way to print this correctly instead of making a bunch of if statements. If I input this: 0 2 3 2 separately it prints out this: 0x + 1y + -2 = 0 but need something like y - 2 = 0

```
import math
def points_to_standard_form(point1, point2): 
x1, y1 = point1 
x2, y2 = point2
A = y1 - y2 
B = x2 - x1
C = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1

if A < 0:
    A, B, C = -A, -B, -C

gcd = math.gcd(A, math.gcd(B, C))
A, B, C = A // gcd, B // gcd, C // gcd

return A, B, C 
x1 = int(input(""))y1 = int(input(""))x2 = int(input(""))y2 = int(input(""))
point1 = (x1, y1)
point2 = (x2, y2)
A, B, C = points_to_standard_form(point1, point2)
if B >= 0:
print(f"{A}x + {B}y + {C} = 0")
else:
print(f"{A}x - {-B}y + {C} = 0")'
```

Comment: You can use SymPy's various simplification routines: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html

Comment: Please, correct your indentation. Also, when running your example with `0, 2, 3, 2`, I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`, which doesn't happen for other inputs (e.g. `0, 2, 3, 4`).

Comment: For your purposes, `if` statements are probably the most straightforward way to get what you want. Also, I don't understand how typing `0, 2, 3, 2` would print out `y - 2 = 0` or `3x + 1 = 0`. Does inputing 4 numbers result in 2 separate equations?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print equations in a readable format and avoid writing out a bunch of if statements, [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) can be a great option. Here's a script that uses sympy to achieve what you want:

```
import sympy as sp

def points_to_standard_form(point1, point2): 
    x1, y1 = point1 
    x2, y2 = point2
    A = y1 - y2 
    B = x2 - x1
    C = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1

    if A < 0:
        A, B, C = -A, -B, -C

    # Using sympy's gcd function to simplify the coefficients
    gcd = sp.gcd(A, sp.gcd(B, C))
    A, B, C = A // gcd, B // gcd, C // gcd

    return A, B, C 

# Taking input for two points
x1 = int(input("Enter x1: "))
y1 = int(input("Enter y1: "))
x2 = int(input("Enter x2: "))
y2 = int(input("Enter y2: "))

point1 = (x1, y1)
point2 = (x2, y2)
A, B, C = points_to_standard_form(point1, point2)

# Constructing the equation using SymPy
equation = sp.Eq(A*x + B*y + C, 0)

# Printing the simplified equation
sp.pprint(equation, use_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditional expressions in the f-string.

```
print(f"{'' if A == 1 else A}x {'-' if B < 0 else '+'} {'' if abs(B) == 1 else abs(B)}y {'-' if C < 0 else '+'} {abs(C)}")
```

Comment: This works for most cases but if C = 0 then it shows 0 which shouldn't have

Comment: You can do it with more conditions, it just gets more verbose.